# How to use drop down in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, drop-down-menu, popup

In my application ,I need a drop down menu or pop up window to select languages (English,Arabic,French,Hindi) when click on a button. How to implement and help me to write the code ?

Comment: Ya i think this is good, but how can i implement

Comment: Use a UITableView it will serve as a superb makeshift dropdownlist....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy and simple way to design a drop down list is by representing it like a `UITableView` and some animation. This makes it look really like a dropdownlist. Here is a code I used for creating one . For this first import the `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` framework.

```
-(IBAction)DropDownTable:(id)sender
{
TableView.hidden = NO;
if(TableView.frame.origin.y ==203)
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL]; 
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
    [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 204, 27, 160)];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [self.view addSubview:TableView];
}

else if (TableView.frame.origin.y == 204)
{
    [TableView setFrame:CGRectMake(224, 203, 27, 0)];
    TableView.hidden = YES;
}

[self.view addSubview:TableActivityLevel];
}
```

First make a tableview , declare its methods and make the array containing the various languages.
Put this function on the click of a `UIButton` and youll see it work !!! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what UIPickerView is for. Honestly, read through Apple's HIG at least once before you start writing code.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the easiest way to do a drop down list ...the easiest way is using a UIActionSheet ...adding multiple buttons makes it behave as a list with a table view that you dont have to manage which is great ..take a look at the screenshot :

[image]